# Use a specific date of Google imagery as basemap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-maps, basemap

I am using Google imagery as a basemap by "XYZ TILES", but I want to choose a specific date to display older images like Google Earth.

Is there any method to specify the date of the Google imagery in QGIS?